# Playwright Java : Playwright fails to click on element whose property is set hidden

Tags: playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test, playwright-java

I tried many locators but looks like its hidden so playwright fails to click any workaround please help

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Comment: please add your whole code which we can copy and run.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit of a dirty way to do it but you can change the CSS if there is something there that makes it hidden e.g. a class or an attribute, or try and force the click using the DOM which is probably a better way to do it.

```
Locator locator = page.locator("YOUR LOCATOR HERE");
locator.evaluate("node => node.classList.remove('classToRemove');");
//I cannot stress enough that this is a last resort as it can be a bit flakey

//or you could try this which might be a better option for your
Locator locator = page.locator("YOUR LOCATOR HERE");
locator.evaluate("node => node.click();");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using force option of click method will help you:

```
page.locator("some_selector").click( {force: true} );
```

Comment: not helped tried everything

Answer (score 0):

try [dispatchEvent](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-dispatch-event)

Regardless of the visibility state of the element, click is dispatched. This is equivalent to calling `element.click()`.

```js
await element.dispatchEvent('click');
```